# Trouble defining Constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object in common.js file:

```
var KITS=
{
   debug: false,
   default_country : 'xxx',
   franchise : '' 
};

KITS.init=function(cb)
{
   var self = this; 
   $.ajax({
        // ...

            if (typeof cb==='function') (cb)();
        },
    }); 

   if (typeof cb==='function') (cb)();
 };
```

I include this js file in a php file. Could some expert please advise what I need to do so that KITS.init() is automatically called when the KITS object is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need real `constructor`:

```
function KITS() {
    // This is contructor method
    console.log('hello world!');

    // Call your init method if you want
    this.init();
}
KITS.prototype = {
    constructor: KITS,
    init: function() {
        // Do some staff here
    }
};

var kits = new KITS();
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/61feepq5/1/

Comment: Don't forget to put `this.init();` at the end of the constructor, else the OPs problem isn't solved yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

Object literals are not created with `new`, so they wouldn't trigger the constructor even if they had one. They do not have constructors, thanks to not having a prototype of their own:

```js
const foo = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo));
```

Comment: They have prototype, they don't have `prototype` property.

Comment: @Maxx fixed the phrasing. They have a prototype, just not one of their own.

Comment: what you mean? if you create object this way it will have empty object prototype.

Comment: An empty prototype is still a prototype (i.e., `getPrototypeOf` returns not null) but doesn't actually *do* anything. Prototypes and constructors are (unless you intentionally avoid it) rather closely tied in JS.

Comment: It's not empty, it's `Object` instance. you can call `hasOwnProperty` on your `foo` for example. it's called from `foo`'s prototype object.